# Can't update ubuntu 20.04

Tags: updates, 20.04, ppa

I've been trying to update my Ubuntu 20.04 using the command `sudo apt update` but I always get this same error:

```
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/t-tujikawa/ppa/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I tried to add that PPA with `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:t-tujikawa/ppa`
but I get the same output error above.

What should I do to solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove that old repository, since it hasn't been updated.

> The Error above means that the repository does not have a release package of the particular software for your version of Ubuntu. i.e. 20.04 Focal Fossa

Remove the obsolete PPA by running the following command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:t-tujikawa/ppa
```

You can install aria2 from the official Ubuntu release using command:

```
sudo apt-get install aria2
```

Answer (score 2):

Open a terminal and type `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list`
then arrow-down to the line/s with **tujikawa** in them and type a # at the start of the line.
Then save over this file and run your apt commands again.
There is an official aria2 release for 20.04 you can try it `sudo apt-get install aria2`

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove that old repo, since it hasn't been updated in 7 years, and hasn't even got an entry for focal ([see here](http://ppa.launchpad.net/t-tujikawa/ppa/ubuntu/dists/)). The package `aria2` is included in the `focal universe` repo.

Edit the file `/etc/apt/sources.list` and do the following:

Remove the line with:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/t-tujikawa/ppa/ubuntu focal Release
```

And make sure following line is uncommented:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal universe
```

Then you should be able to run your `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` again without errors.

Comment: thank you fellows for your valuable answers, i've finally find the solution